# opengl diffuse light becoming oddly directional, but not changing based on GL_SPOT_DIRECTION

Tags: python, opengl, pygame, lighting

I am doing some very simple diffuse lighting with opengl on a triangle strip (cube). I then tried to add in some rotation, and everything dissolved.

Here is a MRE:

```py
import pygame
pygame.init()
from OpenGL import GL
from OpenGL import GLU
import math
import numpy as np
import copy

def Rec(r, angle):
    x = r*math.cos(angle)
    y = r*math.sin(angle)
    return x, y

def Pol(x, y):
    r = (x**2 + y**2)**(1/2)
    angle = math.atan2(y, x)
    return r, angle

class Cube:
    def __init__(self, pos, size, color):
        self.identity_vertices = np.array(((0.5, 0.5, 0.5),
        (-0.5, 0.5, 0.5),
        (0.5, -0.5, 0.5),
        (-0.5, -0.5, 0.5),
        (-0.5, -0.5, -0.5),
        (-0.5, 0.5, 0.5),
        (-0.5, 0.5, -0.5),
        (0.5, 0.5, 0.5),
        (0.5, 0.5, -0.5),
        (0.5, -0.5, 0.5),
        (0.5, -0.5, -0.5),
        (-0.5, -0.5, -0.5),
        (0.5, 0.5, -0.5),
        (-0.5, 0.5, -0.5)))
        self.redefine(pos, size, color)
        
    def draw(self):
        GL.glMaterialfv(GL.GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL.GL_DIFFUSE, self.color)
        
        GL.glEnableClientState(GL.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY)
        data = (GL.GLfloat * len(self.vertices))(*self.vertices)
        GL.glVertexPointer(3, GL.GL_FLOAT, 0, data)
        GL.glDrawArrays(GL.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 14)
        GL.glDisableClientState(GL.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY)

    def update(self):
        self.vertices = copy.copy(self.identity_vertices)
        self.vertices*=self._size
        self.vertices+=self._pos
        self.vertices=self.vertices.flatten()

    def redefine(self, pos, size, color):
        self._pos = [*pos]
        self._size = [*size]
        self.color = color

        self.update()

display = (600, 500)

screen = pygame.display.set_mode(display, pygame.DOUBLEBUF|pygame.OPENGL)

GL.glEnable(GL.GL_DEPTH_TEST)
GL.glEnable(GL.GL_LIGHTING)
GL.glEnable(GL.GL_LIGHT0)
GL.glLightfv(GL.GL_LIGHT0, GL.GL_DIFFUSE, (1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0))
GL.glLightfv(GL.GL_LIGHT0, GL.GL_AMBIENT, (0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 1.0))

GL.glMatrixMode(GL.GL_PROJECTION)
GL.glLoadIdentity()

GLU.gluPerspective(60, (display[0]/display[1]), 0.1, 100.0)

c = Cube((0, 0, 0), (2, 2, 2), (0.0, 1.0, 1.0))

pos = [0, 8, 0]

rot = math.pi

run = 1
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = 0
    pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if pressed[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        rot += 0.1
    if pressed[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        rot -= 0.1

    pos[0], pos[2] = Rec(8, rot)

    GL.glMatrixMode(GL.GL_MODELVIEW)
    GL.glLoadIdentity()

    GL.glLightfv(GL.GL_LIGHT0, GL.GL_POSITION, pos)
    GL.glLightfv(GL.GL_LIGHT0, GL.GL_SPOT_DIRECTION, [*map(lambda x: math.copysign(1, -x), pos)])
    
    GLU.gluLookAt(*pos, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0)

    GL.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1)
    GL.glClear(GL.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
    
    c.draw()
    
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)
    
pygame.quit()
```

My problem is that the lighting is uniform, with the entire cube being gray or cyan (or something in-between), and that it is not providing a gradient. Also, the cube is most often completely dark, with it showing only on a certain rotation. You can reproduce this problem by using the left and right arrow keys to rotate around the cube

After running some tests, I found that the only time the cube is lit is when the camera is positioned in the negative z-direction, relative to the cube. This would make sense, as the documentation declared that the default direction for lighting is `(0, 0, 1)`. I then tried to fix this by changing `GL_SPOT_DIRECTION` to accommodate for this, but to no avail, as this did not change anything. And, I am using Diffuse lighting, which should not have a direction at all

Why is this odd directionality happening to the diffuse lighting (if that is even the problem, it might be something completely different, it's just what I diagnosed), and how could I fix this?

Comment: Where are the normal vectors ([`glNormalPointer`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glNormalPointer.xml))?

Comment: normals = (0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
                        0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
                        0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
                        0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
                        0.0, -1.0, 0.0,
                        -1.0, 0.0, 0.0,
                        -1.0, 0.0, 0.0,
                        0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
                        0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
                        1.0, 0.0, 0.0,
                        1.0, 0.0, 0.0,
                        0.0, -1.0, 0.0,
                        0.0, 0.0, -1.0,
                        0.0, 0.0, -1.0)

Comment: I tried those normals, however they did not work very well

Comment: Do you know of a good question about normals in general? I'm still a little shaky on them

Comment: *"I tried those normals, however they did not work very well "*  So you decided to remove them?

Comment: It makes no sense to learn about the OpenGL fixed function model, which is deprecated for decades.([LearnOpenGL - Basic Lighting](https://learnopengl.com/Lighting/Basic-Lighting))

Answer (score 1):

If you're using OpenGL fixed-function pipeline, you might need to call `glEnable(GL_NORMALIZE)`. This will normalize every normal that you feed as input to the graphics pipeline (i.e. you want to draw).

Usually, if you know what your normals are and are bound correctly, you don't need this explicit normalization.

Mainly, to create an object, you'd do:

```cpp
glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
{
    glNormal3f(nx, ny, nz);
    glColor3f(cx, cy, cz);
    glVertex3f(vx, vy, vz);
    
    // Here you add your vertices that you might want to draw in triangles
    // 3 x vertices per triangle
    ...
}
glEnd();
```

It might be easier for a cube to use `GL_QUADS`:

```cpp
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
{
    glNormal3f(nx, ny, nz);
    glColor3f(cx, cy, cz);
    glVertex3f(vx, vy, vz);
    
    // Here you add your vertices that you might want to draw in quads.
    // 4 x vertices per quad
    ...
}
glEnd();
```